# Is there a way to combine data from two tables in Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Learning more about how to write a query in Kusto. I have a column in 2 tables that have different Roles, but the column header is Role, that I'd like to combine the data into one column called Roles.

I tried, adding this, | extend Roles = strcat (RoleName, Role), but that just combined the data.

Here is my query attempt, I'm joining 3 tables, 2 of which have the roles. The third is where I'm validating the user aliases.

```
(cluster('****').database('****').****_****** | where Discriminator == 'Service'| where DivisionOid == '******')

| join kind = leftouter cluster('****').database('****').Release_Users on SubscriptionId 

| join kind = leftouter (cluster('****').database('****').Release_AzureAccess
| where RoleId contains "****" and PrincipalType !contains "ServicePrincipal") on SubscriptionId

| join kind = leftouter cluster('****').database('****').Headtrax_PeopleHierarchyV1 on $left.PrincipalName == $right.EmailAddress and $left.LiveEmailId == $right.EmailAddress

| extend Roles = strcat (RoleName, Role)<<--this was my failed attempt at combining the Role columns. That just concatenated.
```

I want to validate each user is active from 2 different tables against a person table. I'm a novice and am struggling with how to get this right. I'm thinking I want to combine the 2 tables into one list rather than trying to combine one column out of the 2 tables. Anyone have any advice?

Comment: it might be easier if you provide a sample, minimal data set (with multiple columns), e.g. using the `datatable` operator, and the expected output you'd want that matches it

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a job for the union operator.

Union takes two or more tables and returns the rows of all of them.

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/unionoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer

Here's an example query from the docs above -

```
let View_1 = view () { print x=1 };
let View_2 = view () { print x=toint(2) };
let View_3 = view () { print x_long=3 };
union withsource=TableName View_1, View_2, View_3
```

produces:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

The answer from Irwin will certainly work. If you want to take his solution and flatten it into one row, you could do that with the summarize function.

```
let View_1 = view () { print x=1 }; 
let View_2 = view () { print x=toint(2) }; 
let View_3 = view () { print x_long=3 }; 
union withsource=TableName View_1, View_2, View_3 
| summarize sum(x_long1), sum(x_int), sum(x_long)
```