# How to concatenate columns for one row without enumerating them?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Given:

```
let table1 = datatable (col1:string, col2:string)
["abc","def"]
;
let table2 = datatable (col3:string, col4:string)
["ghi","jkl"]
```

where `table1 | union table2` gives:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
abc  def
          ghi jkl
```

how to get this instead?

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
abc  def  ghi jkl
```

Assume there might be many more columns, so any solution requiring enumerating all of them doesn't work.

Related question:
[Is there a way to combine data from two tables in Kusto?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56802416/986533)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I know of is:

```
table1 | extend pivot="" 
| join kind=innerunique (table2 | extend pivot = "") on pivot
| project-away pivot*
```